# How to ingest data from Eventhub to ADLS using Databricks cluster(Scala)

Tags: apache-spark, azure-databricks, spark-structured-streaming, azure-eventhub, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm want to ingest streaming data from Eventhub to ADLS gen2 with specified format.

I did for batch data ingestion, from DB to ADLS and Container to Container but now I want to try with streaming data ingestion.

Can you please guide me from where to start to proceed further step. I did create Eventhub, Databrick Instance and Storage Account in Azure.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to follow the documentation ([for Scala](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/structured-streaming-eventhubs-integration.md), [for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/PySpark/structured-streaming-pyspark.md)) for EventHubs Spark connector.  In the simplest way the code looks as following (for Python):

```py
readConnectionString = "..."
ehConf = {}
# this is required for versions 2.3.15+
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString']=sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(readConnectionString)

df = spark.readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load()

# casting binary payload to String (but it's really depends on the 
# data format inside the topic)
cdf = df.withColumn("body", F.col("body").cast("string"))

# write data to storage
stream = cdf.writeStream.format("delta")\
  .outputMode("append")\
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/checkpoint/directory")\
  .start("ADLS location")
```

You may need to add additional options, like, starting positions, etc. but everything is described well in the [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/PySpark/structured-streaming-pyspark.md#event-hubs-configuration).

Comment: Thanks, It worked but how can I see the Dataframe

Comment: you can read from Delta table... Or you can split this into two pieces - loading data & writing it (I've modified the code to show that) - in this case you can do `display(cdf)` if you want

Comment: What should I write in ADLS Location, I'm stuck at there

Comment: depending on how it's allocated - if mounted, then its `/mnt/,.....`, if it's direct URL, then it's `abfss://.....`

Comment: Hey, after few hours when I'm running the same code the job is getting aborted after saving 2,3 files into ADLS. How to overcome this issue?

Comment: it depends on the error

Comment: I pasted the error above please look into it.

Comment: it's better to ask this as an additional question, with more information like databricks runtime version, etc.

Comment: This is the links for continuation of the above discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69662907/not-able-to-write-eventhub-data-into-adls-in-databricks-getting-runtime-error