# Not able to write Eventhub data into ADLS in Databricks, getting runtime error

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

when I'm running the writeStream code in databricks which looks like below:

```
df_out = cdf.writeStream\
  .format("json")\
  .outputMode("append")\
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/checkpoint/directory")\
  .start("/mnt/container-name/folder-name")
```

I'm getting runtime error in databricks:

Now after running the writeStream code I am getting the below error:
How can i resolve this error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink.addBatch(FileStreamSink.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:606)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$5(SQLExecution.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withCustomExecutionEnv$1(SQLExecution.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withCustomExecutionEnv(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$15(MicroBatchExecution.scala:604)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:604)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$4(MicroBatchExecution.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.withSchemaEvolution(MicroBatchExecution.scala:647)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:240)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:293)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:366)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:341)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:268)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find batch /mnt/outputcontainer/Sample/_spark_metadata/709.compact
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.applyFnToBatchByStream(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog.applyFnInBatch(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.CompactibleFileStreamLog.foreachInBatch(CompactibleFileStreamLog.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:278)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the above by changing the code like below:

```
result =cdf.writeStream.format("json")\
.option("path", "/mnt/outputcontainer/writedata2-json")\
.option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/outputcontainer/writedata2-json")\
.start()
```

It worked for all the formats